# Which is true about $Q$ where $Q=I+2P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let ${a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}}$ and ${b_{1},b_{2},...b_{n}}$ be two bases of $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Let P be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries such that $Pa_{i}=b_{i}$ for $i=1,2, ...,n.$ Suppose that every eigenvalue of $P$ is either $+1$ or $-1.$ Let $Q=I+2P.$  Then which of the following statements are true?

1. $\{a_{i}+2b_{i} \mid i=1,2,...,n\}$ is also a basis of $V$.
2. $Q$ is invertible.
3. Every eigenvalue of $Q$ is either $3$ or $-1.$
4. If $\det{P} > 0$ then  $\det{Q} > 0.$

If I consider $a_{1}=2$, $b_{1}=-1$ as bases of $\mathbb{R}$, then $a_1+2b_1$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}$. So (1) is clearly incorrect.

As eigenvalues of $Q$ are $3$ or $-1$ so clearly $Q$ is always invertible and further (4) is also correct.

Am I correct in my reasoning according to me 2,3,4 are correct

Comment: In your counterexample,$ P $ has eigenvalue $-1/2$.

Comment: But, if it had been a valid counterexample then 3. would not be true.

Comment: ohhh, that means $a_i+2b_i$ is never zero because P has eigenvalue 1 or -1

Comment: @Corey I will take care of that. Yes V=$\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

we begin by 3)

we have $\sigma(P)=\{1,-1\}$ and for all polynomials $f$ 
$$
f(\sigma(P))=\sigma(f(P))
$$
so if we take $f=1+2 x$ $Q=F(P)$ and then 
$$
\sigma(Q)=\{f(1),f(-1) \}=\{3,-1\}
$$
so in particular $0\not\in\sigma(Q)$ and then $Q$ is invertible so this give as 2)

but 2) implies that $det(Q)\neq0$,

and we know that $\det(P)=\{ \textrm{Product of all eigenvalues (counting multiplicity)}\}$, so $\det(P)>0$ implies that multiplicity of $-1$ is even, and then the multiplicity of $f(-1)$ is even too, so $\det(Q)>0$ which give 3)

if $a_k$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then as $Q$ is invertible we have $\{Q(a_k)\}$  is also a basis then $(a_k+2b_k)$ is also a basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: Thanx very much for your time. I will be simply pleased if you can explain last line in detail.

Comment: a matrix is invertible if and only if it transform every basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a basis of \mathbb{R^n}$